# MYSQL how to see a table?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am trying to see the data from a table called "places"
The schema that I am calling the "places" from is called "mtoldb"
I have previously successfully loaded data from "places" but I have forgotten how.

I understand this must be a stupid question but I just can't figure out what I need to type to query to make the request.

Please if you could kindly educated me by answering my stupid question, it will greatly help me to move forward.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute queries without a schema qualifier it is necessary to define (activate) a default schema when opening a connection. You can either do that by double clicking on a schema node in the schema tree on the left hand side or use the context menu on such a node and choose:

[image]

Alternatively, you can already select a schema in the connection settings:

[image]

Once you had an active schema and close the connection it will be set automatically on next open. The currently active schema is displayed in bold in the schema tree.